# Debug options are not selectable or clickable in NetBeans 8.0.2 for test files

Tags: windows-7, netbeans

I have just installed NetBeans 8.0.2.  I have been using version 6.9 for years. But with version 8.0.2 I can create junit test files/programs, however, I cannot run them.  If I right click on them, the `Run file`, `Debug file`, and `Test file` options are dimmed; I cannot select them.  What am I missing? How can I run my test programs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can be that you don't have the php netbeans plugin selected.

Go to tools->Plugins and search for the PHP plugin with the folowing description: Provides tools and support for php developemnt. Includes php editor, debugger, samples and documentation